# ASP.NET logout and back button in browser show view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have web application and I make SignIn module, now when I logout and click back button in browser then I see view which should be accessible only after sing in.
How can I prevent this?

I use identity for authorization. In IE it's working but in Firefox and Chrome not working.
Code for logout:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public virtual ActionResult SignOut()
{

     AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
     return RedirectToAction(MVC.Login.Login.SignIn());
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134218/using-the-browsers-back-button-after-signout-allows-access-to-secure-page-as

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using the browser's back button after SignOut() allows access to secure page (ASP.NET MVC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134218/using-the-browsers-back-button-after-signout-allows-access-to-secure-page-as)

Comment: Answers in this question not working for firefox and chrome, but in IE work.

Answer (score 1):

Decorate your controller/action method with `Authorize` attribute like below

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public virtual ActionResult SignOut()
    {
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return RedirectToAction(MVC.Login.Login.SignIn());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but this attribute it's doesn't change anything in my problem :(

Comment: Apply this attribute in all those action methods for which you do not want to show the view without login.

Comment: I have [Authorize]
    public partial class NewsController : Controller and when I logout I still see view in this controller

Comment: I think this is default behavior. But when you click back button after logout and try to access any element (like click button) you will redirect to login page. this is default behovior

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers yes it is but I don't want this behavior. I want not see this view only redirect to login page when I click back button.